# Matplotlib tick label fontweight is limited to a few options

Tags: python, matplotlib

See the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0.0001, 30, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)/x

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.tick_params(which="major", labelsize=14, width=1.3)

for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_fontweight(550) # If change to 551, label will be bold-like
```

Accoding to [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontweight), the paramater can be a numeric value or a string. However, I tested both. It seems that label fontweight is the same for fontweight params in [0, 550], in the range [551 , 1000], it becomes bold. Also, `semibold`, and `bold` seem to have the same fontweight.

I assume a linear change of fontweight, but apparently it is NOT. Anyone can explain why it is so?

Comment: It will also depend on the font you are using. Some type faces have more levels of "boldness" than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, a font only has limited number of font weight, such as `Regular`, `Medium`, `Bold`, etc. The font weights are not infinite.

There is correspondence between the numeric value and finite font weight. For more details, see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5250#issuecomment-452232222).